How can I ignore the occlusion relationship of the mesh in GLSL drawing?

gpu.state.depth_test_set("NONE")
The drawing of the back side (white) should be occluded.
gpu.state.depth_test_set("LESS")
But I don't want it to be occluded by the mesh.
Can I achieve this? How can I do it?
Thanks.

Reading the docs for this function it shows a handful of other options like NONE, ALWAYS, LESS, LESS_EQUAL, EQUAL, GREATER and GREATER_EQUAL. Have you tried any of those?

@Jakemoyo I tried, it still gets occluded by the mesh.
